# How to access returned JSON object from soundcloud api

Tags: json, api, soundcloud

I am trying to access a json object returned from soundcloud. I can access it using the following

```
var myJSON = $.getJSON("http://api.soundcloud.com/users/<myuserid hidden>/tracks.json?client_id=<myclientid hidden>");
```

now, I know all the data has been correctly assigned to the var myJSON, as when I log it to the console, everything is there. It returns something like this:

```
   "[{"kind":"track","id":<trackid>,"created_at":"2012/12/17 21:48:03 +0000","user_id":<myid>,"duration":185147,"commentable":true,"state".......
```

However, when I try to access anything like, say, the title of the first track with:

```
console.log(myJSON[0].title);
```

chrome simply gives the error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

so... I am probably missing something quite basic here. Anybody got any idea as to what I'm doing wrong? Help would be very much appreciated!

EDIT: everything needs to be done inside the $.getJSON call, as such:

```
$.getJSON('http://api.soundcloud.com/users/<userid>/tracks.json?client_id=<client_id>', function(sounds) { **enter whatever code you want to execuse
```

The "function(sounds)" part is what's important to add. Apparently, it's not very straightforward to access anything you get from the JSON object outside of the .getJSON method. (there are some ways, but require some workarounds that I didn't really understand much of). soo... I needed to add all my code inside here.

Comment: how silly of me.. I just found out the data needs to be accessed in a callback function... Thread may be closed ! :-)

Comment: please write down the code that works for you in an answer and mark it as solved so that others know what the problem was. thanks!

Comment: A small tip: instead of using $.getJSON try the SoundCloud JS SDK found here: http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/sdks#javascript